# Validating consumer for wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

We have created a WCF service which is deployed on our application server. Other applications from different servers are consuming this service.
Now we want that we should validate if the other application that is consuming this service is a valid application or not.
Since there are many methods present in the service, we would like to validate the consumer before calling any of these methods.
We can ask the consumer applications to pass details like username, password, server etc.
What will be the best way to perform this validation?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to perform Authentication in web services. here you can find some simple examples: [Authentication for Web Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers)
but i rather to have web service identity class and pass the username and password to the web service. you also can use a `HttpContext` in order to validate the user ip address, agent, host name or .... here is a simple method to show you how:

```
public static string GetUserIpAddress()
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    try
    {
        return context.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
```